# Regular Expression in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

What would a Regular Expression need to allow characters and numbers only, no special characters or spacing in asp.net mvc5?

Comment: Ok. Good luck writing it. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions about code YOU'VE written. it is not a "do my job for me", or "write my code for me".

Comment: i try  [RegularExpression("[^A-Z0 - 9]", ErrorMessage = "No special character or space is"] but it doesn't work @MarcB

Comment: well,  yeah. that'll match ANY one single char that isn't upper case alphabet or digit. you want `^[...]+$` to cover the ENTIRE string.

Comment: thanks @MarcB it's work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally use ranges such as [a-z] and [0-9] to filter out just characters and numbers with an asterisk after it *

I don't have a copy of MVC 5 handy so I don't know what the particular syntax is.

A regex for that often looks like:

```
([0-9]|[A-Z]|[a-z])*
```

It will be very similar in asp.net or mvc, likely.

That searches for all alphabetic characters from a to z, and all numbers from 0 to 9. The asterisk makes it search for multiple characters and not just a single character at a time. The pipe character says "or". Search for characters upper case, or characters lower case, or numbers. The brackets help sort groups.

As I said though you will have to figure it out the specific syntax of your regex library that your programming language uses, as they can differ. There are perl style regexes, and many variations. The above is just a sample. You can test at:
http://regexstorm.net/tester